# Activate alarm, ringtone or audio using ADB?

Tags: adb, alarm, remote-control, ringtone

I have misplaced a junker phone (LG G3 running Lineage).  However, it's still on, and ADB is accessible over TCP/IP.  (The phone doesn't have a SIM, so I can't call it.)

Is there a way to turn on the ringer or other audio from ADB?  I've tried a couple of remote-screen apps (adb-remote-control.jar and scrcpy) but although they appear to connect, and scrcpy even gets a screen image that looks correct, neither of them seem to send events correctly, so I can't control the phone.

I suspect there's a way to launch an app (Phone?  Alarm?) with a "Play Ringtone" intent, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion of [Google find my phone](https://myaccount.google.com/find-your-phone) 
worked: Google knows where your phone is, even if you don't.

From [another user](https://ask.metafilter.com/343287/Activate-Android-Alarm-with-ADB#4922024), you can also do it with ADB:

```
adb push t.mp3 /sdcard/
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///sdcard/t.mp3 -t audio/mp3
```

> (Playing a video file the same way or starting youtube (`adb shell am
>   start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=oVQqmH4ufCQ`)) will not produce any
>   sound if the device is locked it seems like)

Comment: This pops up a player. Is it possible to play back a file without GUI?